# How to change the height of a label during execution?

Tags: ios, uilabel

This sounds simple, maybe I am missing something. I have four labels that I am using in a bar graph style. I want to change the height when the button is pressed to change the height of the label and make the bar graph look properly.

In my header for the labels I have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *transBar;
```

I have been trying to use the following line of code in the method for the button action:

```
//Update the height of the bar graphs.

self.transBar.frame = CGRectMake(133, 283, 100, 200); //200 will be replaced with a variable when working.
```

When I test this I can not get the height to change despite how simple this seems. On the XIB in the size inspector I can easily change the value from 400 to 200 and it moves exactly how I want. I just can not get this to happen in runtime. Any help appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you query the frame.size.height after setting the frame, do you get the desired value?

Comment: Do you want to change the height based on text length

Comment: Dov D. - I do. I checked them with self.transBar.frame.size.x and .y then sent that value to another label I was using to debug and saw the values in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set the label on storyboard, are you using autolayout?

try that, let's see:

```
self.transBar.frame.size.height=200;
```

Comment: I gave this a go and I get "property 'titleLabel' not found on object of type UILabel*". Is there some more information I could give you from my code that would help? Still rather new.

Comment: sorry, titleLabe is a copy/paste mistake from my part. Just remove it.

Comment: Took out the titleLabel but now I get "expression is not assignable."